# OAuth2 Login on Android and iOS

Tags: oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth, google-oauth

I have built a web application that allows users to login with Google and Facebook through OAuth 2.0.  I actually used the [SimpleAuth](https://github.com/crhym3/simpleauth) project on Google App Engine.  In my database I am storing their OAuth ID, which for Google looks like:

`https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawnrcuEaKdY_EMesk8FdeFNGP-cCKJbmVf0`

and for Facebook looks like:

```
facebook:1494270173
```

and I am wondering if I can use the same method on an iOS or Android app.  I know that I will need a much different implementation but will that ID be constant even if I am using a Facebook or Google login on mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google identifier you show is an OpenID2 identifier, not an OAuth 2 one. OpenID2 will not work on iOS nor Android. Not familiar with SimpleAuth, but if you can configure it to use OAuth 2 or OpenID Connect (which is based on OAuth 2, not to be confused with OpenID2), then using the OAuth 2 protocol on iOS or Android will give you the same identifier for the same user.

Comment: is this:  google:101591787505840332546 an OAuth 2 identifier?

Comment: Hey @mariuss, this used to work for me, but only a few days ago it stopped working and now it throws this error com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown. Any idea why? Is there something wrong with my scopes? https://gist.github.com/lawloretienne/7351151